# NHIbernate refreshing a collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections

I know this has been asked, but I can not solve this problem.

Lets say you have an nhibernate object that has a collection.

Problem is, if some object in the collection is updated in the database by a different user (i manually modifiy the database fot testing purposes), I can't seem to find a way to make nhibernate refresh the collection value.

I hace tried refresh, evict, Loading againg... Only closing the session and creating a new one works. But I find this solution problematic and, how hard can it be to tell nhibernate "dude, refresh the items in the collection"?

But anyhow I can't get it working.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you evicting the parent or the child?

Comment: yesssssssssssss. Only works if chances have been made by the session itself. Not if changes were made in the database by another way

Comment: Are you using 2nd level cache ?

Comment: I had this problem with a second level cache and ended up writing a (as clean as could be) wrapper around the `ISession.CacheMode` property. I set it to `Refresh` before reading and back to `Normal` afterwards (only for this specific task that had problems). Unfortunately, without restructuring the entire application (of which I've only been apart of for 1 month.. its like 3 years old..).. this was the only way to get the desired effect.

Comment: +1, I do not feel so lonely.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually supposed to work, that's why it doesn't.

NHibernate uses the a session level cache by default, to optimise reads and track modifications.

It sounds like you're not using a correct unit of work around your data access as your sessions should be scoped down and used only when you need them.

If this is part of a web app, it's recommended you follow a "session-per-request" approach.

If you really wanted this to work, you could probably evict entity and it's children from the session, forcing a re-fetch, but this is nasty and I'd really not advise it.

Comment: I agree on the nastiness. But NH is really cool and the dudes behind it are sharp and smart. I don't think this is how they intended it.

Comment: Evicting the entity do not work! Tried that. That leaves me no choice other than to evict collection items one-by-one. Nasty as you said. On a side note, it's a desktop app and some objects live long.

Comment: Even as a desktop app, you need to work out your unit of work. If it's cached data, disconnect the objects from the session and re-fetch them when you need to update, otherwise multiple clients will have write collisions based on stale data.

Answer (score 0):

Having gone to the trouble of trying to evict, and even considered opening and closing sessions. It sounds as though there is enough headspace in your code to consider doing a filtered get, i.e. get all items of the collection type where the parent id is that of your parent object. You might have to extend your repository or dao, depending on how you are working with NH, but as others have said, it is hard to be more specific without an example. Main point is that you get the child objects in a query for that type, filtered by the parent id.

This would be a fresh get, so you'd get any new or altered objects that were created by some other process, and then you could set that collection as the collection in your parent object. NH should get over this when you try to save as it can make assumptions about your objects and save or update as appropriate. This could be of use to you if there is likely to be some time lag between getting the parent object and saving it again.

Problem with this approach is that a sort of merge type operation is required. You may want to add any new objects that were created in process so that you don't loose your changes when the collection is updated. Hope this helps, give us some more info if you're still stuck.

Comment: Thanks! But I think you lose the beauty and practicity of NH if you replace the cool out of the box collections with filtered gets.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the IDispose interface in you SessionFactory Class.

Just like this:

```
public class YouSessionFactory : INHibernateSessionFactory, IDisposable
{
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    //codes for initial _sessionFactory, for configuration,mapping or something else.
    //balalalalalala
    //....

    public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
    {
        return _sessionFactory;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_sessionFactory.IsClosed || _sessionFactory != null)
        {
            _sessionFactory.Close();
            _sessionFactory.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```